# Coda 2 and github setup: cannot clone and connect to repository

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository, coda

I am going mad trying to get Github repositories to work in Coda 2.

- I did not create the Github repository, but I am a contributor.
- I installed [**Git**](http://git-scm.com/downloads) and followed [**these instructions as how to activate**](http://readwrite.com/2013/09/30/understanding-github-a-journey-for-beginners-part-1)
- (I *did* install Github, but it is not clear to me if I *really* need
  it or not..)
- (I installed xcode, but it is not clear to me if I did it correctly
  and if I really need it or not..)

At some point in the process I actually got to clone/download the repository, though I was never able to push/commit/upload.

Now, however, the source tab does not even give me the option of cloning a Github repository. Here are some screenshots that might be helpful.

In the file-tab of preferences, Coda 2 has - by itself it seems - figured out the Git tool path.
[image]

I have tried adding and removing all sorts of information in each of these boxes, with no luck. I cannot figure out *what* should go *where*, and what should definitely *not* go anywhere:

[image]

I have primarily tried to get the clone link from Github:

[image]

...and this is what my source tab shows me: I am not even able to get the Github repository from here (I was able to previously. What changed? Not sure...:S)

[image]

..and yes, I have googled and searched widely. I am sure this is just silly simple, but I cannot figure it out.

Somewhere it said I needed a key from the admin, but he - apparently - cannot find one.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a Git repository in that folder, which you can just delete, or delete the containing folder and start again.